# Cutting out a specific part of a string using simple_html_dom?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I use the following code to cut out a div from a site.

```
$url = 'http://mypage.com/index.php';
$html = @file_get_html($url);
$GetScore = $html->find('div[class=ismSBValue]',0);
echo $GetScore;
```

This returns.....

```
<div class="ismSBValue">
    <div>   58
        <sub>pts</sub>                                     
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I cut out ONLY the 58 value?

I can do the following...

```
$GetScore = $html
 ->find('div[class=ismSBValue]',0)
  ->find('div',0)
   ->innertext;
```

to get it down to this....

```
   58
    <sub>pts</sub>
```

Is there some way to exclude the `<sub>` tag using simple_html_dom? or am I stuck to using `str_replace()` or `strpos()` to cut it further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clone then delete u dont want

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(){
var a = $('.ismSBValue').clone();
    a.find('sub').remove();
        console.log($.trim(a.text()));
})
```

PHP

```
$html = str_get_html('<div class="ismSBValue">
    <div>   58
        <sub>pts</sub>                                     
    </div>
</div>');


$html->find('div[class=ismSBValue]',0)->find('div',0)->find('sub',0)->innertext = '';
$a = $html->find('div[class=ismSBValue]',0)->plaintext;
echo trim($a); //58
```

Comment: This looks like it might work, but I'm not sure how to use this. Is it javascript? I copied all your code into my page and it gives me a blank page. I also put `<script type="text/javascript">` around it but still nothing. Thanks if you can help.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. It also works without the javascript part.

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove the `sub`, you might need it later. A simple regex will work:

```
preg_match('/\d+/', $html->find('div.ismSBValue div', 0)->text(), $match);
echo($match[0]); // 58
```